# Why reverse DNS resolution is not implemented in Twisted?

Tags: python, dns, twisted

I am not found in `twisted.names.client` method for reverse dns resolution. Is possible to do this with twisted - without blocking (for response time)?

Is blocking the query with `socket.gethostbyaddr()`?

Comment: Doesn't `t.n.client.lookupPointer` provide PTR record look up?

Comment: Not working for me:

`
>>> from twisted.names import client

>>> client.lookupPointer('8.8.8.8')
<Deferred at 0x7f40341eaf80 waiting on Deferred at 0x7f4034183320>

>>> _
<Deferred at 0x7f40341eaf80 current result: <twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.names.error.DNSNameError'>>>
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('66.35.39.66')
('dornkirk.twistedmatrix.com', [], ['66.35.39.66'])
>>> 
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('8.8.8.8')
('google-public-dns-a.google.com', [], ['8.8.8.8'])
`

Answer (score 1):

Reverse DNS lookups should probably be a built-in part of the API, but they are quite easily implemented as a simple string transformation. In fact, [the Twisted documentation uses reverse name lookups as its main way of explaining the client API](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/names/howto/client-tour.html#a-simple-example).  Have a look at that linked document and hopefully it answers your question.